# Haskell bit arrays

Tags: arrays, haskell

How much space does an `STUArray` with `Bool` elements use for each element? Does it actually pack things down to one bit? Or does it use an entire byte per element?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The source code of the [array](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array) package shows that yes, multiple `Bool` are packed together as bits into byte arrays.

Doesn't seem to be documented(?)